# Add checkbox to ASP.NET grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I am trying to enable bulk deleting in my web app. The data I am displaying is in a `GridView` and I want to add a column which would contain one checkbox (or any alternative) for every row. The user could mark rows to delete and then delete all of them at once.

When I add a `CheckBoxField`, it must be bound to a column which I, naturally, don't have in the DataTable. I tried adding a new column to the DataTable programatically, but it is rendered as read-only whatever I do.

The data is retrieved from the DB into a DataTable, which I add to a DataSet and bind to the GridView as its data source.

Is there a way I could achieve this?

Comment: How do you want to delete ? in a button click ? If so why do you need a column you can just check the grid for checked columns right?

Comment: @Krishna Yes, on a click of a button all selected should be deleted. But I don't know how to select the rows. CheckBox column is data bound, so I can't use that. Renders as read only.

Comment: That's what I am saying, there's no need for it to be data bound

Comment: But how to add an editable checkbox to every row which is not data bound?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `TemplateField` to your GridView with the CheckBox. You can even add one in the header for a "select all" checkbox. You will still need a separate delete button

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" CssClass="headerCheckBox" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" CssClass="rowCheckBox" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> .headerCheckBox").change(function (e) {
            $("#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> .rowCheckBox input").each(function () {
                $(this).prop("checked", $(e.target).prop("checked"));
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I've added a javascript function that checks/unchecks all the checkboxes if the header is clicked.