# In Grid View, Select/Deselect all checkbox in a column when checkbox in Header is clicked

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

> When I click the checkbox in header it should select all checkbox in
>        that column. Am not using Item template and Header Template for 
>        checkbox.

```
protected void gv_ProjectResourceDatasetAccess_RowDataBound(object 
sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //DataRowView drview = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
                CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
                chk.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(chk);
                e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes.Add("OnClick", "return 
SelectAll(this)");
        }

    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataColumn col in ds_DatasetAccess.Tables[0].Columns) {
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
            // cb.id = ... and other control setup
            // add your control here:
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(cb);
            i++;
        }
    }
 }

 <asp:GridView id="gv_ProjectResourceDatasetAccess" runat="server"  
OnRowDataBound="gv_ProjectResourceDatasetAccess_RowDataBound"  
CssClass="table datatable-basic table-striped table-hover dataTable no-
footer"></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: WHat have you tried? All I see is code to add checkboxes to a GridView. And do you need to change it client side or server side?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681996/add-checkbox-to-asp-net-grid-view) to get you started.